# UPDATE with SELECT Variable - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that has all the names of the databases that are on a particular server. I want to be able to update the DBSizeMB column with the pertaining DB size.

So far my code is:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(100)

UPDATE master.dbo.mytableName
    SET DBsizeMB = (SELECT total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
                      FROM master.sys.master_files)
    WHERE DBSizeMB = NULL
          AND DatabaseName = @DatabaseName
```

Right now the SELECT total size part is summing up all of the databases' sizes.

How can I set it to update each individual database?

Comment: Would not recommend storing custom data in `master`.

Comment: Your code isn't going to work quite like this at all. sys.master_files is ALL the files for every database. And definitely do NOT create your own tables in master. This is a very bad idea.

Comment: Okay, but it is on a development server and it was approved by senior DBA's to be stored on the system db

Comment: Not that hard to create a `Utilities` database for stuff like this, for a start later migrating `master` elsewhere is not (really) possible.

Comment: As I understand it, the only thing that should go in master is stored procedures. And even then, we're talking about global utilities like sp_Who2 and sp_Blitz, not ones that are used by applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Correlate` the `sub-query`

```
UPDATE mt
SET    DBsizeMB = (SELECT total_size_mb = Cast(Sum(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8, 2))
                   FROM   master.sys.master_files f
                          JOIN sys.databases d
                            ON f.database_id = d.database_id
                   WHERE  d.NAME = mt.DatabaseName)
FROM   master.dbo.mytableName mt
WHERE  DBSizeMB IS NULL
```

`JOIN` version

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT total_size_mb = Cast(Sum(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8, 2)),d.name
         FROM   master.sys.master_files f
                JOIN sys.databases d
                  ON f.database_id = d.database_id)
UPDATE mt
SET    DBsizeMB = c.total_size_mb
FROM   master.dbo.mytableName mt
       JOIN cte c
         ON c.NAME = mt.DatabaseName
WHERE  DBSizeMB IS NULL
```

Also as mentioned in comments, do not create tables in `Master` database. Even in [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187837.aspx) it is mentioned that

> Do not create user objects in master.

Comment: I needed to change 'WHERE DBSizeMB IS NULL' instead of '= NULL'